# How can I use map-reduce with MongoDB and JS to obtain this?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm completely new at JS so i'm having some big issues using map reduce with mongodb by my lack of knowledge, I have this collection called **dailyAlerts**:

```
{
        "_id" : 25,
        "title" : "Other… Title Test Polygon 2",
        "alertDescription" : "Other… Description Test Polygon 2",
        "alertDateTime" : 1507784400100,
        "alertLatitude" : 20.5774756,
        "alertLongitude" : -103.3795262,
        "alertType" : 9,
        "userName" : "Azgad",
        "photoLink" : "www.google.com",
        "videoLink" : "www.google.com",
        "__v" : 0
}{
        "_id" : 26,
        "title" : "Other… Title Test Polygon 4",
        "alertDescription" : "Other… Description Test Polygon 4",
        "alertDateTime" : 1507784400100,
        "alertLatitude" : 20.5774756,
        "alertLongitude" : -103.3795262,
        "alertType" : 5,
        "userName" : "Azgad",
        "photoLink" : "www.google.com",
        "videoLink" : "www.google.com",
        "__v" : 0
}   
{
        "_id" : 27,
        "title" : "Other… Title Test Polygon 6",
        "alertDescription" : "Other… Description Test Polygon 6",
        "alertDateTime" : 1507784400500,
        "alertLatitude" : 20.5774756,
        "alertLongitude" : -103.3795262,
        "alertType" : 1,
        "userName" : "Azgad",
        "photoLink" : "www.google.com",
        "videoLink" : "www.google.com",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

The important field here is "alertType", I want to use map reduce to give me the count of all alerts based on the alertType (Values available are 1-9), othewrise put 0 if no documents for that alertType are found, also I need to show me the total of all the documents processed to insert them in another collections, something like this:

```
{
        "_id" : 4,
        "dateRecord" : 3500,
        "type1Count" : 0,
        "type2Count" : 10,
        "type3Count" : 20,
        "type4Count" : 30,
        "type5Count" : 0,
        "type6Count" : 50,
        "type7Count" : 60,
        "type8Count" : 70,
        "type9Count" : 80,
        "totalCount" : 320,
}
```

I would really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: What do the first two properties of your desired output refer to?

Comment: _id is just an autogenerate id, and dateRecord is the past day of the current execution date in Milliseconds (If today is Oct 14th, should be 13th)

Comment: But I suppose your question is not about generating those two values, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your question is not about the first two property values in your desired output. The counts can be collected with `reduce` like this:

```js
var data = [{ "alertType" : 9 }, { "alertType" : 5 }, { "alertType" : 1 }];

var counts = data.reduce ( (counts, obj) => {
    counts[obj.alertType]++;
    return counts;
}, Array(10).fill(0) );

console.log(counts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This returns an array where at index *k* you'll find the number of occurrences where `alertType = k`. As arrays also have index 0, that first value will always be 0. You can of course convert this to a non-array object, or any other data structure.

Comment: I change some things to code but it's giving me just a Array full of zeros, do you a clue why? //var data = [{ "alertType" : 9 }, { "alertType" : 5 }, { "alertType" : 1 }];

var data = db.dailyalerts.find({},{_id: 0, alertType: 1}).toArray();
var counts = data.reduce ( (counts, obj) => {
    counts[obj.alertType]++;
    return counts;
}, Array(10).fill(0) );

counts

Comment: My Bad! I forgot to put use <DB>, it's working now, thank a lot!